# Snowflake “Bytes Scanned” is less than “Bytes written to Result”. Why is this difference?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-execution-plan

When I’m running a query, I sometimes see “Bytes Scanned” is less than “Bytes written to Result”. Why is this difference?

For e.g , I ran this below query –

SELECT * FROM "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF100TCL"."CUSTOMER"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42dpf.png)

Comment: In DB terminology, scanning generally refers to reading from a table. If some of the data to satisfy a query is cached or perhaps if it's indexed, it wouldn't count as "scanned".

Comment: It would be scanning compressed data on micropartitions and writing the actual data is my initial thought, but I am not able to find any documentation to prove this point

Answer (score 0):

I ran the query, and got different results depending on the destination of the query.

First, almost the same query as yours gives me similar results:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF100TCL"."CUSTOMER";
```

[image]

But if the destination is set to a new table, then I get this:

```sql
create temp table stack_test
as
SELECT * FROM "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF100TCL"."CUSTOMER";
```

[image]

You can see that writing the results to a new table has a lower "Bytes written" than "Bytes scanned".

I'd say that "Bytes written" is larger in the previous case because the query needs not only to be ran and the results stored, but also the results need to be sent to the presentation layer for you to see them.

Comment: Felipe Hoffa thanks for response. But It does not satisfy my query. I need more clarity on below 2 part 1> Same query give different Byte scanned on every execution. 2> Bytes scanned is sometimes less sometime more than Bytes written for same query if you run multiple time.

Comment: To provide a satisfactory answer I'd like to understand: How are you planning to use these answers?